# How can I render heatmap contours from QGIS into tiles?

Tags: qgis, tiles, gdal-contour

I have a heatmap and contours in QGIS, and I want to export these heatmaps as tiles. This works well with tiff, but I want to include contours into images, to make them look better. In QGIS, I can make a contour layer, but it can't be exported into raster format, only in vector.

How can I make a raster countour layer or vector tiles with QGIS or linux-based gis tools?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your raster continuous or classified? GDAL contour doesn't care if your data is elevation, foliage density, population... if you have a *continuous* raster you can contour it; be sure to set an appropriate contour interval for your data type.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I edited the question to make it clear. I did make contours from the raster, the problem is to add them to web based map as tiles.

Comment: Doh! I can help with gdal_contour but not with web... sorry.